# How to increment and decrement values using react and redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

In my example I have two buttons "increment" and "decrement". I want to show digit that will increase when increment button is clicked. and 
decrement when decrement button is clicked.

here is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/UwQjdyRJhz4H3orUc3m5?p=preview

```js
const { createStore, bindActionCreators, applyMiddleware,combineReducers  } = Redux;
const { Provider, connect } = ReactRedux;
const thunk = window.ReduxThunk.default;

const abc = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_DATA':
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  };
};
const pqr = (state = 0,action) => {
  console.log('in redux', action.type)
  switch(action.type){
    case 'INC':

      return state +1
    case 'DEC':
      return state -1
      default :
      return state;
  }
}
const cmpbind = combineReducers({
  abc,
  pqr
})
const store = createStore(cmpbind, applyMiddleware(thunk));

class First extends React.Component {
  constructor (props){
    super(props);
    this.getData = this.getData.bind(this);
  }

  getData(){
    this.props.load();
  }
  inc (){
    console.log('ince', this.props)
    this.props.increment();
  }

  dec (){
    console.log('dec')
    this.props.decrement();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.getData}>GET DATA</button>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.props.data)}</pre>

        <button onClick={this.inc.bind(this)}>INCREMENT</button>
        <p>{this.props.digit}</p>
        <button onClick={this.dec.bind(this)}>DECREMENT</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
} 


const actions = {
  load: () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
      return axios.get('data.json').then((response) => {
        dispatch({  
          type: 'SET_DATA',
          payload: response.data,
        });
      });
    };
  },
  increment: () => {
        return {
            type: 'INC',
        }
    },
     decrement: () => {
        return {
            type: 'DEC',
        }
    }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    data: state
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  load: bindActionCreators(actions.load, dispatch),
});

const AppContainer = connect(mapStateToProps,   mapDispatchToProps)(First);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AppContainer/>
  </Provider>
  ,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Are those imports working for you?

Comment: Look here for a todo app example with Redux as well as inspiration for variable names. http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html

Comment: @user944513 do not add react-native tag to reactjs only questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` function to receive the data from reducers and actions like

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    data: state.abc,
    digit: state.pqr
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  load: bindActionCreators(actions.load, dispatch),
  increment: bindActionCreators(actions.increment, dispatch),
  decrement: bindActionCreators(actions.decrement, dispatch)
});
```

**[PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/GSSaGAVCJ7hAFwgTTPx6?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to change `mapDispatchToProps` to :

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch),
});
```

and your `onClick` listeners can be changed to :

```
  getData(){
    this.props.actions.load();
  }
  inc (){
    console.log('ince', this.props)
    this.props.actions.increment();
  }

  dec (){
    console.log('dec')
    this.props.actions.decrement();
  }
```